# String split in 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to split the following string into 2 arrays.

First array from the beginning to **'/'** and the second from **'/'** to end.

Also, I've tryied with replace to remove the **'/'** but returns error.

```
var str = 'word1-word2/word3+word4'.replace(/\+|/|-/g,' ');
```

http://jsbin.com/kubezabemu/1/edit?js,console

The wanted output should be like:

```
var arr1 = ['word1', 'word2'];
var arr2 = ['word3', 'word4'];
```

Comment: try to split both arrays one at a time?

Comment: i want to split the str in two arrays, i ve tried to replace the / with ' ' but it returns error

Comment: "I want to split the following string into 2 array" => you already provided the solution in your last code snippet. I guess, however, that your problem statement is a bit more generic. What does it look like? Do you want to "split a string first by all occurrences of the slash and then split each chunk by all occurrences of the minus or plus sign"?

Comment: I don't see how replacing fits into the solution to your problem. If you want to split by certain characters, removing them beforehand will render your splitting efforts useless...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this way you get an array that contains unlimited of your expected arrays

```
var arr = 'word1-word2/word3+word4'.split("/");

var res = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ 
 str=arr[i].replace(/\+|-/g,' ');
 res.push( str.split(" "));
}
console.log(res)
```

console output

```
[["word1", "word2"], ["word3", "word4"]]
```

Comment: how can i replace the &times; or × in the replace function?http://jsbin.com/joratihono/1/edit?js,console

Comment: well thats simple `.replace(/\+|-|×/g,' ')`

Answer (score 3):

Here you go. Split on `/` first and then on the respective separators.

```
var arr = 'word1-word2/word3+word4'.split('/'), 
    arr1 = arr[0].split(/[+-]/),
    arr2 = arr[1].split(/[+-]/);
```

Comment: The - + are not in the same position each time, its there a way to do this in a dynamic way? Like replacing all the symbols and then split?

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks!

Comment: @hiero, coming back to my comment to your question.... Amit perfectly answered your question. If the problem is more generic than you stated, please rephrase the question such that we can help you better: Do you always have two arrays? Or does the `/` occur many times? Then, can there be more than two words per array? Or are there always two? When are they separated by a plus sign as opposed to a minus sign?...

Comment: @tomyself *the feel when you've hit 200 and upvotes come on.* :(

Comment: @chiccodoro the '/' its just one time, but the along with [- +] i have × this character, witch represent multiplication '&times;' as I see if i use this character in my replace it returns an error http://jsbin.com/joratihono/1/edit